# Alternative to saving state of activity : ram check [Android]

Tags: android, android-activity, memory, webview, ram

So theoretically, if I had a webview that loaded multiple pages in one session AND in one activity, if I was unable to save the state of that activity like I normally would via Bundle onSavedInstanceState, is there a way to prompt the app to check for available ram usage/memory?

I'm looking at a way to maintain activity state with webviews using the "Do not keep activities" turned on via developer options. Basically, when the app launches a new activity from an activity with a webview, on return, the pages that the user progress would have vanished because this would be a new activity instance.

Like, I'm looking for a possibility to check available ram usage via code to prompt the app to quit should there not be enough memory to use.

Generally, this should happen as Android will take the least frequent activity on the stack and destroy that to make more ram space available, so this is more of a theoretical question than a practical one.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your theoretic exercise is pointless. If Android needs memory, it just kills off background processes. It does not selectively destroy `Activity`s within an application. The documentation alludes to this possibility, but in reality this is never done.

The developer option "Do not keep activities" is something that always breaks complex applications when it is turned on, and it is something that **can be used for troubleshooting and testing certain behaviour**, however it doesn't really mimic the actual behaviour of the Android framework and it breaks a lot of code. For example, try using `startActivityForResult()` with that option enabled and see for far you get!